# Python Django Import data to Postgres

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

I am new to Django and wondering how to insert the data from a excel/csv/txt file into Postgres using Django. I was able to successfully connect to database and create a table but ca you guys help me with how to import and export data using Django models

Edit:

```
csv_filepathname= "C:/Users/Desktop/MF.csv"
djang_proj_folder= "C:/Users/"

import sys,os
sys.path.append(djang_proj_folder)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] ='cartel_app.settings'

from cartel_app.models import mf


import csv
datareader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter='|')

for row in datareader:
    record_type = row[0]
    unique_system_identifier = row[1]
    uls_file_number=row[2]
    ebf_number=row[3]
    call_sign=row[4]
    partition_area_idnumeric=row[5]
    lower_frequency=row[6]
    upper_frequency=row[7]
    def_und_indicator=row[8]
    defined_partition_area=row[9]
```

was successfully able to load the data into table, but was only able to load 2 rows, it has more than 1000 rows, where am i doing wrong ?? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you post some more details but I think this will not change the method you take. For example, you have to import Book data from csv (use [native csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)) / excel (use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)), which has fields, like title, isbn, page_count and etc.

First of all, my recommendations would be to rely on django's ORM and create model (Book) with corresponding fields. Then just read the source file and do the main job - insert (for efficiency reasons, I recommend to use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)):

```
entries = []
for line in source:
    entries.append(Book(title=line['title'], ... etc
Book.objects.bulk_create(entries)
```

In addition, for dumping data based on model, please use [built-in capability](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) of django:

```
python manage.py dumpdata AppName.ModelName --format json
```

and voila. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on your models, and how the csv needs to be processed before saving.

For example purposes, I'll be using this model:

```py
# students/models.py
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name} (grade={self.grade})"
```

To import the csv, we can use the [`csv` module from the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

```py
# students/data_import.py
import csv
from students.models import Student

def load_csv_file(path):
    with open(path) as file_obj:
        reader = csv.reader(file_obj)

        for row in reader:
            Student.objects.create(
                first_name=row[0],
                last_name=row[1],
                grade=int(row[2]),
            )
```

Now, we can test by importing a properly formatted csv:

```py
# There are no products in the database to start
>>> Student.objects.count()
0

# Here's a csv with some example data:
>>> print(open("students.csv").read())
first_name,last_name,grade
John,Doe,5
Jane,Doe,8

>>> from students.data_import import load_csv_file
>>> load_csv_file("students.csv")
>>> Student.objects.count()
2
>>> Student.objects.values()
[
    {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "grade": 5},
    {"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe", "grade": 8}
]
```

Comment: I have added a new comment, can you please check and let me know what wrong am i doing

Comment: i fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @BharatGuda can you please explain how you fixed your issue so that future visitors to this question understand the problem and how to fix it? Once you've done that, please select one of the replies as the correct answer.

Comment: above code worked fine for me, i just had to refresh the database. it took sometime to load all the records.